# Using table variables from SQL 2008 in Delphi

Tags: sql, delphi

Switching to SQL 2008 we are using table variables now as parameters for stored procedures. While it's not a problem to use them in .NET, we have some old code in Delphi where we want to switch to these new procedures as well.

The problem we cannot find how to set parameters for TADOCommand to table value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, TADOCommand (or any other VCL database component, for that matter) does not support passing table variables around.  You would likely have to execute direct SQL statements instead.